# Does Ubuntu Netbook Remix require an Intel Atom processor?

Tags: laptop, netbook, ubuntu-netbook-remix, intel-atom, intel-celeron

I have a laptop with an Intel Celeron 1.6GHz processor and 512MB of RAM - a similar spec to current netbooks.

Will I be able to install [Ubuntu Netbook Remix](http://www.canonical.com/projects/ubuntu/unr) on this laptop or will it only work with Intel Atom processors?

> Minimum hardware requirements:
>
> - Processor: Intel® Atom™ processor
> - RAM: 512 MB
> - Storage: 4 GB Flash disk (SSD) or hard disk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses the standard 32 bit x86 kernel, and therefore will work on any intel based system, including your celeron.

Comment: @gorilla - Now installed! 10.4 netbook remix works great. I asked the Q because I could never get 9.10 netbook remix working and having looked at the requirements today.

Comment: Strange that it should call out the Atom specifically like that, if it doesn't care.